# Using basic Embedded Systems APIs

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I am trying to learn the embedded systems with the help of online resources but I am finding it highly difficult. I have some questions regarding how to use the auto generated APIs? I am using nucleo-f446re development board on stm32cubeIDE.
After going through a lot of online lectures, for an example I am able to understand that that if I have to Initialize a GPIO Pin, I have to use a below sequence of code as shown below:

```
int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClockConfig();
    GPIO_Init();                              // High Level GPIO Initialization
    while(1);
    

    return 0;
}    

void GPIO_Init(void)
{
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitTypeDef ledgpio;
    ledgpio.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    ledgpio.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    ledgpio.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&ledgpio);
}
 void SystemClockConfig(void)
{
  
}
```

As shown in the GPIO_Init function, there is a sequence of API and Handler function used. My question is that should I keep on remembering the sequence of APIs and handlers used and do similar thing for other peripherals like Timers, Uart,CAN, PWM etc or is there some other way? Also, if I use some other microcontroller, will the sequence of the APIs used for the same thing as above will be similar or a lot different? Please guide.

Comment: What is your *coding* question?  Because if it's "do I have to learn to be successful?" then the answer is yes.  Embedded work is demanding.  What you improperly call "APIs" are often not even completely consistent across a single manufacturer's line of parts.  And the HAL functions you're using are legendary for being riddled with errors and bloated.

Comment: Thank you @TomServo. I got your point. One needs to write all the APIs from scratch using the Reference manual.

Comment: @ManuChaudhary : I don't think Tom is saying that at all - you may have in fact missed his point.  It is simply that you cannot expect a common interface across all targets.  I am not sure how you interpreted that as _"write all the APIs from scratch"_.

Comment: Thank you @Clifford. Thank you for your response. I got a really great help from your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "***the*** embedded systems"

The use of the definite article there is not appropriate - there is no one  embedded platform, API or framework.

In your question the *"auto generated APIs"* is a particular feature of ST's STM32CubeMX framework.  The initialisation sequence and API is specific to both the STM32 and the CubeMX / STM32 HAL API.  It is certainly not the only API for STM32 - you could program it directly at the STM32xxxx.h defined register level, use the Standard Peripheral Library (that preceded CubeMX as ST's SDK offering), or use an alternative framework such as Mbed.

If you are targeting something other than STM32, then CubeMX is entirely unavailable to you - other vendors may provide their own proprietary frameworks - or nothing.  The ARM CMSIS is an API common across ARM Cortex M devices regardless of vendor, for example. While Mbed is applicable to a wide range of ARM targets, and a higher level ecosystem than either CMSIS or CubeMX.  It is most directly supported by Mbed specific COTS development boards such as ST's Nucleo series.  Putting it on custom hardware is slightly more work.

If you are not using an ARM based microcontroller, then Mbed is not an option either and there are few if any cross-platform, multi-vendor frameworks or SDK for architectures other than ARM.

Essentially with bare-metal embedded systems it is most often a matter of familiarising yourself with a particular target through its data sheet and user manuals, picking a development toolchain and SDK/libraries/framework from possibly several options and running with it.

While there is no common API for *all embedded systems* there are common principles, techniques and patterns that are generally applicable, but certainly no common API or hardware initialisation approach.  There are various general texts on the subject - online resources tend to be specific to a particular framework or architecture, as do many online courses (necessarily so, as the subject is otherwise too broad).

My advice would be to continue as you are, but be aware that what you are learning is a specific and narrow aspect of embedded systems in general and do not get too hung up on the specific and accept the general principles.

Comment: @old_timer :  While I appreciate the fixing of the typos, I'll stick to British English spelling if you don't mind ;-).  US spelling makes it too easy to use a Z in Scrabble than its letter score of 10 deserves - ruins the game.

Comment: my apolgies didnt realize that was a British spelling, Cortex was mangled so when I went in for that I right clicked a few more on the way.

Comment: @old_timer No problem, I'm bi-lingual - English and American ;-)

Comment: this makes sense now depending on computer, site or whatever, I have seen the z and s thing over the years and now I question the spelling of some words I thought I used to know...before computers started trying to help...bottom line is that both are right (and both are wrong)...

Comment: this may be literally the first edit of someone elses I have made, it was the Cortex typo I intended to fix...

Answer (score 2):

Learning how a certain lib works is pretty useless. Instead, if you truly wish to learn microcontroller programming, you should look at how the library does things behind the lines, then write similar code yourself. In this case, load the whole project into a decent IDE. Then keep digging (in ST's default Eclipse-based IDE, use the F3 key) in those function calls until you find the definition of `HAL_GPIO_Init`.

It will most likely write to at least 3 different registers:

- the actual data register used for I/O
- the data direction register used to state if pins should be input or output
- the pull up/down register enabling internal pull resistors in case the port is input, possibly also setting up/down

All microcontroller GPIO work somewhat similar function-wise, as in they'll have some flavour of the above registers. Usually also an interrupt enable register + a rising/falling edge register for interrupts.

Exactly how these registers work in detail is MCU-specific, so once you know the name of the registers from the library code, you can go and look them up in the manual and read how they should be used. This is a 32 bitter so they will be 32 bit registers.

The more high-end microcontrollers (such as ARM) also have various routing registers that you have to set, in order to route a certain hardware function to a certain pin. These tend to be tricky to get right, so it's a big time saver if you have some example code to look at.

Comment: STM32 parts have pretty complex alternate function pin mapping too I would say. I would not say that is a feature of "more advanced microcontrollers" in particular.  It is true that the GPIO function is the default for all pins that support GPIO so this is the simple case.  It is largely a matter of the number of peripherals available vs the number of pins available rather than how "advanced" the microcontroller is perhaps.  And STM32 parts do carry a relatively large set of peripherals on the die.

Comment: @Clifford "Advanced" is relative, in this case pretty much all 32 bitters have complex pin routing (at least true for every ARM and PPC I've worked with), as opposed to 8 and 16 bitters where it is usually more straight-forward, if at all supported.

Comment: OK.  When you'd said "more advanced" I read that as "more advanced than the device in this discussion", your comment seems to suggest "more advanced amongst microcontrollers in general".  It seems we are in agreement in any event.  I simply did not want the OP thinking that his device did not have pin mapping.

Comment: @Clifford I tweaked the text slightly in the last paragraph to clarify.